# Triple buffering without buffers?

Tags: 3d, metal

[Metal Best Practices Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/BufferBindings.html) states that

> The setVertexBytes:length:atIndex: method is the best option for binding a very small amount (less than 4 KB) of dynamic buffer data to a vertex function

I believe this means that instead storing uniforms in an overly complicated manually memory managed dynamic buffer, it's best to simply update model/view/projection matrices without using any buffer at all, by using `setVertexBytes` and `setFragmentBytes`.

My question is, that in this case, as there is no dynamic buffer at all (only static vertex data), what are we calling triple buffering?

Is it simply because we have a semaphore with `value: 3` left now?

Comment: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ might also be an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `setVertexBytes` and its ilk instead of explicitly using buffers to pass in dynamic data, I would agree that you're not "triple-buffering" in any real sense. In fact, you could omit the semaphore, since at that point, there is no resource to which you're guarding concurrent access.

You may (but probably won't) still block waiting on a drawable to become available, but that's a limitation of the presentation architecture, and a separate concern from whatever buffer management you might or might not be doing.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about blocking without semaphore? Since the render loop is limited to 60 FPS and the frame time is about 1.5 ms for the CPU (in case of a simple example), I want some command to take the blocking function of the semaphore, wouldn't I?

Comment: Perhaps, but if you’re using an `MTKView` and/or display link timer, that role is already being performed for you. Are you driving rendering from somewhere other than the main thread and/or running your own timer?

Comment: I'm just using the simplest MTKView example (Metal Game App with buffers and semaphore removed).

Comment: In that case, `MTKView` internally runs its own `CADisplayLink` (or `CVDisplayLink` in the case of macOS), which only generates as many callbacks as there are frames to be displayed (most commonly 60Hz).